# Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML with localhost

Tags: html, iframe, office365, powerpoint, office-online-server

I want to use this method to upload a powerpoint presentation:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

but i'm using XAMMP to use localhost server so i need something like this

```
 <iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose a local web server to the internet (the free version should be enough).

These are the actions I followed to run this in my localhost. I tested it with a dummy presentation.

### 1. Create an ngrok account

Go to [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) website and create a free account. Then, grab your authtoken.

### 2. Install ngrok in your computer

Run the following commands in your command line (Linux or Windows using WLS):

```
sudo apt-get install ngrok-client
ngrok authtoken [enter_your_authtoken_here]
ngrok http 80
```

The last command will expose your local web server to a public URL. This assumes that you are already running a webserver in localhost (port 80).

### 3. Prepare the Embed code

Save an `.html` file with the embed code, replace the `src` attribute to include the new URL provided by ngrok. Make sure your file_name.pptx is also accessible in localhost.

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>
```

Replace `https://www.your_website` accordingly, with the URL generated by ngrok. (You can grab the exposed URL from the command line, see picture below).

[image: Example: Shows ngrok running in the console]

That's all. Here is an example showing the results I got when I tested a dummy presentation using this approach.

[image]